# Discord bot only replying to initator

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am starting with a new Discord bot using **discord.js**. I am still learning things but am curious if it is possible to send a reply to only the initiator, not the channel.

`Channel.send` and `message.reply` are both public to all.

```
const discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new discord.Client;
const prefix = '!';

client.once('ready', () => {
  console.log('Ready!');
});

client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content === 'ping') {
    message.channel.send('Pong!');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To dm the person who said the message do

```
message.author.send("hullo");
```

To send it to someone else,

```
let user = client.users.cache.get(`PUT-YOUR-ID-HERE`);
user.send("hullo");
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Does this mean that discord does not have a way to return something to the channel only visible to the user but everyone will be able to see it. Otherwise it needs to be a direct message?

Comment: yes, you have to send a direct message.
also if this helped you could you mark it correct? its the check mark

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
message.author.send("text to send")
```

To send a direct private message

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways to respond to a user and i'll explain all three of them. To reply to the user (author) only, you might want to use `.reply()` method. And this is how you use it:

```
message.reply("I replied to you :)!");
```

To send a message to the author in private only, you want to use the `author.send()` method. This will start a private conversation in direct messages and only your bot and the author will be in this conversation.

```
message.author.send("This is a private conversation, nobody will ever know about.");
```

Just to send a message in the channel, use `channel.send()`.

```
message.channel.send("This is a regular message, no user is pinged.");
```